# How to pass data between two vue js component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I'm building an app making use of vue.js The app basically has two js files. The first is used as a reference on the landing page while the other one is for the backend. There's need for me to communicate between these components. I initially used localStorage to pass data from the landing page to another inner page but decided to make use of event bus like so.

```
    Vue.component('loan-calc', {
        template: `<div class="row calc-holder" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800">
    <form>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="card_one">
                <label for="">Loan Amount</label>
                <p>The amount you want to take</p>
                <div class="loan-amount-form">
                    <i class="icon naira">
                        <svg width="15" height="13" viewBox="0 0 15 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path opacity="0.4" d="M14.814 5.764H13.302V7.726H14.814V9.22H13.302V13H11.286L8.244 9.22H4.716V13H2.232V9.22H0.684V7.726H2.232V5.764H0.684V4.288H2.232V0.219999H4.158L7.38 4.288H10.818V0.237999H13.302V4.288H14.814V5.764ZM4.716 7.726H7.056L5.472 5.764H4.716V7.726ZM10.116 7.726H10.818V5.764H8.55L10.116 7.726Z" fill="#03293D" />
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                    <input type="text" name="LoanAmount" v-model="LoanAmount" />
                    <i class="icon pencil">
                        <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path opacity="0.4" d="M10 0C4.47 0 0 4.47 0 10C0 15.53 4.47 20 10 20C15.53 20 20 15.53 20 10C20 4.47 15.53 0 10 0ZM13.1035 5.0684C13.2435 5.0684 13.3833 5.1224 13.4883 5.2324L14.7676 6.5117C14.9876 6.7217 14.9876 7.0732 14.7676 7.2832L13.7676 8.2812L11.7188 6.2324L12.7188 5.2324C12.8237 5.1224 12.9635 5.0684 13.1035 5.0684ZM11.1289 6.8145L13.1875 8.8711L7.12891 14.9316H5.06836V12.8711L11.1289 6.8145Z" fill="#03293D" />
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card_two">
                <label for="">Loan Tenure</label>
                <p>How long before you pay back completely</p>
                <div class="loan-term-form">
                    <input type="text" v-model="LoanTenure" />
                    <i class="icon pencil">
                        <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path opacity="0.4" d="M10 0C4.47 0 0 4.47 0 10C0 15.53 4.47 20 10 20C15.53 20 20 15.53 20 10C20 4.47 15.53 0 10 0ZM13.1035 5.0684C13.2435 5.0684 13.3833 5.1224 13.4883 5.2324L14.7676 6.5117C14.9876 6.7217 14.9876 7.0732 14.7676 7.2832L13.7676 8.2812L11.7188 6.2324L12.7188 5.2324C12.8237 5.1224 12.9635 5.0684 13.1035 5.0684ZM11.1289 6.8145L13.1875 8.8711L7.12891 14.9316H5.06836V12.8711L11.1289 6.8145Z" fill="#03293D" />
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card_three">
                <label for="">Repayment</label>
                <p>Amount to be paid monthly</p>
                <div class="form-repay">
                    <label for="">
                        <i class="icon">
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 15 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="M14.814 5.764H13.302V7.726H14.814V9.22H13.302V13H11.286L8.244 9.22H4.716V13H2.232V9.22H0.684V7.726H2.232V5.764H0.684V4.288H2.232V0.219999H4.158L7.38 4.288H10.818V0.237999H13.302V4.288H14.814V5.764ZM4.716 7.726H7.056L5.472 5.764H4.716V7.726ZM10.116 7.726H10.818V5.764H8.55L10.116 7.726Z" fill="#03293D" />
                            </svg>
                        </i>
                        12,580
                    </label><small>per month</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card_repayment">
                <label for="">Repayment Type</label>
                <p>Select how you wish to replay the loan</p>
                <div class="loan-term-form">
                    <input type="text" list="repaymentType" v-model="RepaymentType" />
                    <datalist id="repaymentType">
                        <option>Direct Debit Mandate</option>
                        <option>Cheques</option>
                        <option>Cash</option>
                    </datalist>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card_four">
                <a href="/LoanOrigination/LoanRequest/" @click="getEstimatedLoanCal">
                    APPLY NOW <i class="icon">
                        <svg width="8" height="13" viewBox="0 0 8 13" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M0.584961 11.5841L5.17099 6.99807L0.584961 2.41205L1.99896 0.998047L7.99899 6.99807L1.99896 12.9981L0.584961 11.5841Z" fill="white"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </a>
                <p>No collateral Needed</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>`,
        data() {
            return {
                LoanAmount: null,
                LoanTenure: null,
                RepaymentType: null,
                Repayment: null
            }
        },
        props: {
            _LoanAmount: this.LoanAmount,
            _LoanTenure: this.LoanTenure,
            _RepaymentType: this.RepaymentType,
            _Repayment: this.Repayment
        },
        methods: {
            getEstimatedLoanCal: function() {
                if (this.LoanAmount != null) {
                    // Creat an event bus tha will share data between components
                    this.$root.$emit('msg_from_loancalc', this.LoanAmount);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

On receiving the event on the other component, the items were not displayed on console log

```
Vue.component('loan-overview', {
    template: `<div>
<div class="card">
    <div class="contain">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="left">
                <h3 for="">Your Loan</h3>
                <p>₦{{LoanAmount}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h3 for="">Loan Tenure</h3>
                <p>{{LoanTenure}} Months</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="t">
                <h4>Repayment</h4>
                <p class="l_p2">₦{{LoanAmount}}<span>per month</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="t">
                <h4>Repayment Type</h4>
                <p class="l_p2">{{RepaymentType}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="left">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editLoan">
                    <i class="icon">
                        <svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none"
                             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M15.0534 3.6979L12.4445 1.07568C12.2721 0.904151 12.0388 0.807861 11.7956 0.807861C11.5524 0.807861 11.3191 0.904151 11.1467 1.07568L1.8978 10.3112L1.05336 13.9557C1.02423 14.0889 1.02523 14.227 1.05628 14.3597C1.08734 14.4925 1.14766 14.6167 1.23285 14.7232C1.31804 14.8297 1.42595 14.9158 1.54868 14.9752C1.67141 15.0347 1.80588 15.066 1.94225 15.0668C2.00579 15.0732 2.06982 15.0732 2.13336 15.0668L5.8178 14.2223L15.0534 4.99568C15.2249 4.82328 15.3212 4.58998 15.3212 4.34679C15.3212 4.1036 15.2249 3.8703 15.0534 3.6979ZM5.37336 13.4223L1.92003 14.1468L2.70669 10.7601L9.62669 3.86679L12.2934 6.53346L5.37336 13.4223ZM12.8889 5.88901L10.2222 3.22234L11.7689 1.68457L14.3911 4.35123L12.8889 5.88901Z"
                                  fill="white" />
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                    Edit
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclaimer">
                    Learn More <i class="icon">
                        <svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none"
                             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M5.40002 4.20001H6.60002V3.00001H5.40002V4.20001ZM6.00002 10.8C3.3534 10.8 1.2 8.64665 1.2 5.99999C1.2 3.3534 3.3534 1.2 6.00002 1.2C8.64663 1.2 10.8 3.3534 10.8 5.99999C10.8 8.64665 8.64663 10.8 6.00002 10.8ZM6.00002 0C2.6862 0 0 2.6862 0 5.99999C0 9.31385 2.6862 12 6.00002 12C9.31383 12 12 9.31385 12 5.99999C12 2.6862 9.31383 0 6.00002 0ZM5.40002 8.99999H6.60002V5.39998H5.40002V8.99999Z"
                                  fill="white" />
                        </svg>
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="details_steps">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>
                <i class="inactive"><span>1</span></i> Personal
            </h4>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h4>
                <i class="inactive"><span>2</span></i> Work
            </h4>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h4>
                <i class="inactive"><span>3</span></i> Additional Info
            </h4>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h4>
                <i class="inactive"><span>4</span></i> Bank
            </h4>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h4>
                <i class="inactive"><span>5</span></i> Documents
            </h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            LoanAmount: null,//localStorage.getItem("loanAmount"),
            LoanTenure: null,//localStorage.getItem("loanTenure"),
            RepaymentType: null,//localStorage.getItem("repaymentType"),
            Repayment: null //localStorage.getItem("repayment") * (0.04)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$root.$on('msg_from_loancalc', LoanDetails => {
            this.LoanAmount = LoanDetails.a;
            this.LoanTenure = LoanDetails.b;
            this.RepaymentType = LoanDetails.c;
            this.Repayment = LoanDetails.d;
        });
        console.log("Message received from Loan calc Component", this.LoanAmount, this.LoanTenure, this.RepaymentType, this.Repayment);       
    }
})
```

I would appreciate the help  be glad if you can help as I'm new to vue.js

Comment: On first glance your log is outside your eventHandler.
Would start by changing the code in the ```mounted()``` lifecycle handler to

`this.$root.$on('msg_from_loancalc', LoanDetails => {
        console.log("Message received from Loan calc Component", this.LoanAmount, 
        this.LoanTenure, this.RepaymentType, this.Repayment); 
        this.LoanAmount = LoanDetails.a;
        this.LoanTenure = LoanDetails.b;
        this.RepaymentType = LoanDetails.c;
        this.Repayment = LoanDetails.d;
    });
`

Comment: use can use props

Comment: First Suggestion - please extract the template HTML into `<script id='templateName'></script>` and then use the `templaceName` in `template: '#templateName'`

Comment: EventBus is also fine. You can check out Vuex which is state management library for Vuejs. If the components are in the same parent then props can be used. But if they are in different parent components then evenbus is easier like u are doing now

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla: How would or should I do the extract?